# Default WebPart in page layout is not editable

Tags: web-part, office-365, page-layout

I have added a `WebPart` using in the `Page Layout`, but it is not editable, even though I specified `AllowEdit = true`.

```
 <WebPartPages:ContentEditorWebPart webpart="true" runat="server" 
                            __WebPartId="{76b0ec97-18db-4d84-9d22-b1fc1476d9e6}"
                            Title="Quick Link"
                            Description=""
                            PartImageLarge="/_layouts/15/images/mscontl.gif"
                            AllowEdit = true
                            AllowZoneChange =true
                            IsVisible =true
                            PartOrder="0"
                            ID="g_d2e2e9c9_5554f_4c66_8ab8_07b5ee9d871d"
                            ChromeType="TitleOnly"
                            ContentLink="<% $SPUrl:~SiteCollection/Style Library/Html/Links.html %>">
 </WebPartPages:ContentEditorWebPart>
```

Comment: what all permissions this particular user has on Site collection?

Comment: Make sure webpart is added in   <!--SPM:<%@Register Tagprefix="WebPartPages" Namespace="Microsoft.SharePoint.WebPartPages" Assembly="Microsoft.SharePoint, Version=15.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=71e9bce111e9429c"%>-->
                <div xmlns:ie="ie">
                    <!--MS:<WebPartPages:WebPartZone runat="server" AllowPersonalization="false" ID="WebPartZone" FrameType="TitleBarOnly" Orientation="Vertical" Title="Web part zone">--> and not under                   <!--MS:<Publishing:EditModePanel runat="server" PageDisplayMode="Display" CssClass="edit-mode-panel">-->

Comment: @AkshayRandive Site collection administrator